# C++ Polymorphism error - Not allowing me to create child object from parent type

Tags: c++, polymorphism, shadowing

I have a class Simulation that is supposed to generate 20 customers. I have a Customer class defined in code not shown. I also have the classes RegularCustomer and PremiumCustomer defined (also not shown).

RegularCustomer and PremiumCustomer derive from abstract class Customer. In my simulation class, I'm supposed to generate 10 RegularCustomer and 10 PremiumCustomer. Right now, I'm just focusing on generating 10 RegularCustomer.

Here is my code for the Simulation class:

```
class Simulation
{

private:
    vector<RegularCustomer> regCustList;

public:
    void printResult() {
        cout << "Simulation Run" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            RegularCustomer regCust = generateCustomer(1);
            regCustList.push_back(regCust);
        }
    }

    Customer* generateCustomer(int flag) {
        if (flag == 1) {
            return new RegularCustomer();
        }
        else {
            return new PremiumCustomer();
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see, the generateCustomer() method has a return type of Customer. This is because, I need the *same* method to be able to return both child types of Customer. I however get this error:

```
E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "Customer *" to 
"RegularCustomer"
```

This is confusing as I thought polymorphism allowed child classes to be created from parent type. Such as this:

```
Parent parent = new Child();
```

Though, that could be called shadowing, I mix those two up all the time. But should still work regardless.

Any suggestions would be great thanks!

Comment: You need to learn more about pointers if you want to use objects polymorphically.  Returning a base class by value doesn't allow returning a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```cpp
RegularCustomer regCust = generateCustomer(1);
```

is trying to convert a *pointer* to `Customer` to a `RegularCustomer` *object*. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

One way around this is to have your vector hold pointers to `RegularCustomer`, or even better `unique_ptr`s. If you store raw pointers it will be your responsibility to delete those pointers before the vector is destroyed.